# Number of elements are too large

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting this error when I try to train data using tensorflow.

> tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1651] OP_REQUIRES failed at
>   gather_nd_op.cc:47 : Invalid argument: params.NumElements() too large
>   for int32 indexing: 2153378304 > 2147483647

The relevant code is this and it works as expected for smaller dataset. How do I apply it to larger data?

```
ml_df_collect = list()

similarity_input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=(None))
similarity_message_encodings = embed(similarity_input_placeholder)
with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    session.run(tf.tables_initializer())
    message_embeddings_ = session.run(
        similarity_message_encodings,
        feed_dict={similarity_input_placeholder: messages},
    )
corr = np.inner(message_embeddings_, message_embeddings_)

ml_df_collect.append(corr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gather_nd` is failing because the tensor is too large for `int32` indices.

The TensorFlow documentation specifies that `gather_nd` can also accept `int64` indices (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd).

Using `int64` instead of `int32` for your indices tensor is probably the solution.

Comment: How do I specify type of int64 instead of 32?

Comment: It depends on how the rest of your code is written. For example, `tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.int64)` or `tf.placeholder(tf.int64)` produce `int64` tensors.